# How to set UseSubmitBehavior="False" in one place for the whole web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, webforms

I want all of the buttons in my asp.net web forms application to have UseSubmitBehavior="False" but I don't want to go through all my pages trying to hunt down each and every last button and set the property individually.

I am hoping there is a way to do this globally, for example in the web.config file. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *not* a page property or something like that

this is a button property which allowes submit via  `__doPostBack`

You Can't do this globally via web.config ( or in any other way).

Comment: I wouldn't say it can't be done 'in any other way' -- if he doesn't mind the overhead, on page load he could loop through all controls, find the ones of type Button, and apply 'theButton.UseSubmitBehavior = false;'

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I was talking about a global way. you can not do it in a site-global way.(web config as he mentioned).

Comment: Well if he uses Master Pages, one piece of code in the site master would take care of it. I think that would fulfill his request as it keeps him from doing it individually.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev ive made a test.it can be done with master page. I wonder if it is sufficient for the OP.

Comment: Thanks Royi. I'd also like to add the following quote from msdn, "This property [UseSubmitBehavior] cannot be set by themes or style sheet themes." - so I must concede that setting the property for each individual button is the only way (with the exception of @MikeSmithDev 's solution but I don't want to have the overhead in this particular web application - thanks for the suggestion though!).

Answer (score 0):

The reason for wanting to set UseSubmitBehavior="False" is to stop the form from submitting when the user presses enter. If this is your goal then the following will interest you:

Another way to do this is to use JavaScript. This shifts the overhead of MikeSmithDev's suggestion to the client which might be more acceptable depending on your scenario.

Please note that the following JavaScript makes use of the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) library:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    preventSubmitOnEnter();
});

function preventSubmitOnEnter() {
    $(window).keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            var $targ = $(e.target);

            if (!$targ.is("textarea") && !$targ.is(":button,:submit")) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```